# Postgres does not have time to write data from RabbitMQ

Tags: postgresql, rabbitmq

Rabbit has a queue that the consumer listens to, written in python:

```
def generate_callback(table_name, count_columns):
    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        body_json = json.loads(body)
        sql = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({', '.join(list(body_json.keys())[:-1])}) VALUES ({r'%s, ' * (count_columns - 1)}%s)"
        result = prepare_data(body_json)
        try:
            db_cursor.execute(sql, result[:-1])
            db_conn.commit()
            channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
        except:
            print(f"Error in message:\n{body}")
    return callback

# Начинаем слушать очередь
channel.basic_consume(
    queue='applications_dwh',
    on_message_callback=generate_callback('appl_test', 21),
    auto_ack=True
)
channel.basic_consume(
    queue='deals_dwh',
    on_message_callback=generate_callback('deal_test', 11),
    auto_ack=True
)
```

The problem is that the consumer manages to write a relatively small queue, but there is a queue in which messages are only accumulating and the consumer does not have time to parse them

P.S. there was an idea to do insert in batches, but I'm not sure if this is the right way
P.S.2 a large amount of data is saved in jsonb format

I expect stable data loading

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.